# Which is a better option for random name of file on disk sha1 or uniqid?

Tags: php, file, upload, unique, sha1

To store uploaded files by users on remote server inside disk folder I change the name of file to

```
$filename = '/tmp/foo.txt';
$newName = sha1_file($filename); // 40 characters 
//or I can do
$newName = uniqid($filename) // 13 characters
```

Which is a more robust method for new name that is not likely to fail  ??
Thanks.

Comment: @thilo by fail I mean stability of that function .

Comment: But sha1_file is handy for 1) tracking duplicates 2) creating a balanced tree naming schema

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better solution is to use `tmpfile()` or `tempnam()`. Either one is guaranteed to create an unused file that won't collide and can't be "intercepted" by rogue processes changing permissions on you. `tmpfile()` automatically deletes the file when it's closed, whereas `tempnam()` keeps it around

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

Comment: Yes, use the `tempnam()` function to get an unused filename in a given directory. Other solutions with hash and random values can return filenames which are already in use, and why would you want to leave this to luck if there is an easy way to do it right?

Comment: I agree,tempnam() is better than uniqid(). It might not be better than sha1_file though - you may want to store identical files with identical names, to avoid storing the same data twice.

Comment: @Matt - The solution with sha1_file() will probably work well in practice, though i'm not comfortable with it. Either you _know_ that a file is the same and should be overwritten/reused, or you shouldn't assume it. Hash algorithms are designed to allow collisions, in such (rare) cases you would overwrite/share data of distinct users.

Comment: Rare is an understatement - git uses SHA1 file content hashes, and there is a nice analysis in the Pro Git book pointing out just how incredibly unlikely these are (http://progit.org/book/ch6-1.html - see "A SHORT NOTE ABOUT SHA-1")

Comment: @Matt - Ok you are right about that, it's a very very very very rare case :-) . But if there is a safe way to do it, why not use it? If you want to share identical files (we are not sure jason wants that), you can store the hash value somewhere and check files for equality when a collision occurs.

Comment: this tempnam function must be using inside someway of generating unique id may be uniqid??

Comment: The point I am trying to make is just that tmpnam is not safer in any real way. The probability of a failure because of a meteor strike/power cut/disk outage/memory corruption is of much much more concern than that of SHA1 hash collision.

Comment: @jason bourne - The tempnam function will generate a random filename, but additionally it will proceed generating names as long as there are existing files with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Neither should give names which collide. sha1_file is a lot more compute intensive, but it has the useful property that if two users upload exactly the same file, it will be given the same name and you store it only once. If you don't expect a lot of people to upload the same file, or don't care about storing it twice, uniqid will run a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

In either cases you want to check whether the file already exists. 
If you want to be 100% safe and the files are not too big then just use

```
sha1_file($filename);
```

This will pull the SHA-1 for the whole file so even if the file already exists the contents is the same.

Peace

Answer (score 1):

Sha1 - as with any hash function has the advantage of beeing deterministic. In your case this might be unwanted.
Using just a hash-function for this will result in collisions on equal files (which can occur in real life).

Having uniqueid is better in this case. 
Although the smaller range of 13 characters would indicate a much higher probability for collisisons, this is not the case, because it is rare, that  2 files are uploaded in the very same moment. Even than, using the filename as prefix (and by this increasing the length of your $newname) will save you from collisions in most cases.
If you want to make sure, you might want to add some loop checking for existing file, and rebuilding the name, until you have no collision (or some break-condition is given).